# Uploading file using NetworkStream

Tags: c#

We are trying to get image uploading working with TinyPic that tracks the progress of the upload. We used HttpWebRequest earlier but since that doesn't support tracking progress, we decided to try low level methods such as TcpClient.

The code when executed gets "stuck" in this line:

```
int networkBytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The code hangs there for more than one minute.

Please have a look at this code for the full class: 
http://paste2.org/p/331631

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks, 
McoreD from ZScreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error is caused when client and server are not synchronized, that is may be the server is listening at the same time when client is sending data. may be you should send an empty line or something else, to give server know that he should send data.HttpWebRequest know about that is why he work so good:) You can try to record traffic by tcp snipper in case of HttpWebRequest and compare it with the traffic of NetworkStream

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. Did that exactly using the help of Wireshark and the problem was solved. :)